# how to recall Items using EWS?

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

How to recall Items using EWS?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RecallItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <t:ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="[ItemId]"/>
      </t:ItemIds>
      <t:DeleteType>SendOnly</t:DeleteType>
      <t:SuppressReadReceipts>false</t:SuppressReadReceipts>
    </RecallItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The code above not work.
It returns `ErrorInvalidRequest`.
How to recall items?

Answer (score 0):

Message recall is available after you click Send and is available only if both you and the recipient have a Microsoft 365 or Microsoft Exchange email account in the same organization. So, for example, a message sent to or from a Hotmail, Gmail, or live.com account can't be recalled.

*Make sure that the recipient uses Office365 or Exchange account in the same organization.*

Also you may check how the [Delete an item by using the EWS Managed API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-work-with-exchange-mailbox-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange#delete-an-item-by-using-the-ews-managed-api) works.

Comment: That is delete items.Is there any way to recall message?Is there any api?

Comment: Is your message sent to the same O365 or Exchange org?